# Returning multiple server operations in Meteor in one call. How to?

Tags: mongodb, function, meteor, server, session-variables

I've very new to this but essentially I want to create a cleanup function that runs on the server that I can call at any time to reset various things like collections and sessions in one call.

I'm really very new but this is what I have so far.  Can someone please help fill me in where I'm going wrong?

I am trying essentially to return two things (and many more in the future) at once.  I've done some research on this but it's as far as I can fathom with my skill level at the moment.

It would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    return Meteor.methods({

      //Use this to emplty the form data
      cleanUpForms: function() {

        var cleanUpPhoneNumbers = orgPhoneNumbers.remove({});  
        var cleanUpEmailAddresses = orgEmailAddresses.remove({});  

        return {
          cleanUpPhoneNumbers : cleanUpPhoneNumbers;
          cleanUpEmailAddresses : cleanUpEmailAddresses;
        }

      }

    });

  });
}
```

By the way, the current error is for line :

```
cleanUpPhoneNumbers : cleanUpPhoneNumbers;
```

It states:

```
Unexpected token
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.  I essentially want it to run multiple cleanups in one go, all called from the client to the server with the above method.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fully adjusted code for any future reference which may help others.  Thanks so much to FloatingCoder for the help.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    return Meteor.methods({

      removeAllNewOrgs: function() {
        var PhoneNumbers = newOrgPhoneNumbers.remove({});  
        var Organsations = newOrgansations.remove({});  

        //If we want to return the data, to get around only being able to return one thing at a time we're return via an array.  CLEVS!
        return {
          PhoneNumbers : PhoneNumbers,
          Organsations : Organsations
        }
      }

    });

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected token is likely for the ; at the end of the line. When building a JSON object, use a comma between the elements...

```
    return {
      cleanUpPhoneNumbers : cleanUpPhoneNumbers,
      cleanUpEmailAddresses : cleanUpEmailAddresses
    }
```

I think this will return the number of items that where removed. Is that what you are expecting?

Also, just in case you didn't know, you can run 'meteor reset' from the command line to erase ALL collections.